# SSLHandshakeException with openfire (localhost)

Tags: java, android, ssl

Logcat:

```
     javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:322)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.waitForHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:623)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:585)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initReaderAndWriter(XMPPTCPConnection.java:627)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPTCPConnection.java:734)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$1000(XMPPTCPConnection.java:133)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1023)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:931)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:950)
  Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:225)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:114)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:550)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:318)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.waitForHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:623) 
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:585) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initReaderAndWriter(XMPPTCPConnection.java:627) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPTCPConnection.java:734) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$1000(XMPPTCPConnection.java:133) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1023) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:931) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:950) 
  Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:324) 
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:225) 
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:114) 
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:550) 
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:318) 
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.waitForHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:623) 
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:585) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initReaderAndWriter(XMPPTCPConnection.java:627) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPTCPConnection.java:734) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$1000(XMPPTCPConnection.java:133) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1023) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:931) 
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:950) 
     03-24 15:56:06.295 17245-17715/de.meisterfuu.smackdemo W/System.err:   ... 8 more
     03-24 15:56:06.295 17245-17715/de.meisterfuu.smackdemo W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I am getting this error with localhost using openfire for android

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error is *Trust anchor for certification path not found*

That means that the server's certificate is not signed by a certificate authority the client knows, or that there is an intermediate certificate that needs to be included on the server.

If for some reason you don't expect the server to have a valid certificate, you need to set a custom `TrustManager` that won't check it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew mcGuinness.  Actually i forgot to write this line   builder.setSecurityMode(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);   . Now my problem has been solved.